# Error al crear extensiones en CKAN

Tags: python, python-2.7

¿Me pueden decir cómo resolver este error?

> ImportError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ExampleIAuthfunctionsPlugin'

Mi clase:

```
# encoding: utf-8

import ckan.plugins as plugins

class ExampleIAuthFunctionsPlugin(plugins.SingletonPlugin):
    pass
```

seguido del codigo del entry point si es necesario:

```
entry_points='''
[ckan.plugins]
example_iauthfunctions=ckanext.iauthfunctions.plugin:ExampleIAuthFunctionsPlugin
''',
```

Comment: Christian la verdad es que desconozco por completo CKAN, por el código supongo que estas siguiendo el tutorial de la documentación: http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/tutorial.html. Dos cosas, supongo que has guardado el contenido de plugin.py antes de intentar instalar el plugin. Por otro lado,  comprueba que el nombre del módulo donde guardas la clase es plugin.py, así como las rutas. Como digo desconozo CKAN por lo que son solo ideas peregrinas.

Comment: Si, asi es, estoy siguiendo ese tutorial pero no entiendo porque ese error si aparentemente esta todo bien, lo que preguntas tambien ya esta verificado y esta perfecto por eso nose la verdad...gracias por tu ayuda, una pregunta mas...cuales son las rutas?

Comment: Con lo de las rutas solo me referia a que este guardado `plugin.py` en la carpeta adecuada del directorio Python `ckanext-iauthfunctions/ckanext/iauthfunctions/plugin.py` que supongo que sí. Supongo que puedes importar e instanciar la clase desde otro módulo sin problemas (es decir, si creas un módulo en `ckanext-iauthfunctions/ckanext/iauthfunctions/` o te situas con el intérprete en esa ruta y haces `from plugin import ExampleIAuthFunctionsPlugin` se importa sin errores).

Comment: Asegúrate que has escrito bien el nombre de la función. En el error aparece *functions* con `f` minúscula.

Comment: Buena observación @ChemaCortes, es lo primero que repasé en el código (donde todo parece estar en orden) pero no me había percatado sobre lo que  comentas en la traza del error. Si no se trata de un fallo al copiar el error, eso explicaría por supuesto el problema. Sin duda algo está mal porque el error no concuerda con el código. Saludos.